# Django return different class-based view according to whether an object has been created

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I would like ,if possible to have a function where according to whether an object exists,it would either call my CreateView or my UpdateView and redirect to the corresponding template of the view.

I have already created the CreateView and UpdateView and they both work fine,seperately.

I tried to create a function to call the relevant template each time, but it doesn't redirect . Which I think is wrong to think that I need it to redirect but I can't think something else.

here's my code:

```
def getArchived(request):
    archived = ''
    q = request.GET.get('q',None)
    archived = Archivedfolder.objects.get(folder=q)
    template_create = "commondev/Archivedfolder/create.html"
    template_update = "commondev/Archivedfolder/update.html"
    if archived.pk:
        return render(request,template_update)
    else:
        return render(request,template_create)
```

At  the code I am showing I use render() . I have also tried HttpResponse(),HttpResponseRedirect(),redirect(),render_to_response().

**EDIT**
My UpdateView:

```
class DataUpdate(UpdateView):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.app = ''
        self.app1 = self.request.GET.get('app',None)
        if  self.app1 != None:
            self.app = self.app1
        else:
            self.app = eval(self.kwargs['table'])._meta.app_label
            print(self.app)
        self.model = apps.get_model(app_label=self.app, model_name=self.kwargs['table'])
        self.template_name = "{0}/{1}/update.html".format(self.app,self.kwargs['table'],self.kwargs['table'])
        self.form_class = eval('{0}Form'.format(self.kwargs['table']))
        self.myurl = str(self.app) + ':data-list'
        self.back_url = reverse_lazy(self.myurl, kwargs={'is_list':0,'app':self.app,'table':self.kwargs['table']})
        #self.success_url = reverse_lazy('ori_building:data-update', kwargs={'is_list':0,'app':self.app,'table':self.kwargs['table'],'form':self.kwargs['form'],'pk':self.object.pk})
        self.request.session['url'] = reverse_lazy('{0}:data-list'.format(self.app), kwargs={'is_list':0,'app':self.app,'table':self.kwargs['table']})

        return super(DataUpdate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


    def get_object(self):
        # # Call the superclass
        obj = super(DataUpdate, self).get_object()
        return obj


    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(DataUpdate, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        kwargs.update({'app': self.app})
        kwargs.update({'table': self.kwargs['table'].lower()})
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        if self.kwargs['table'] == 'Archivedfolder':
            q = self.request.GET.get('q',None)
            deviant = Libraryfolder.objects.get(pk=int(q))
            obj = self.model.objects.get(deviant=int(deviant.pk))

            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user_id = self.request.user.pk
            obj.deviant = deviant
            obj.save()
            form.save_m2m()
        else:
            obj = form.save()
            form.save_m2m()

        if self.request.POST.get('is_popup'):
            obj = form.save()
            popup = 1
            a = checkPopup(obj)
            return a
        else:
            return super(DataUpdate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(DataUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['app_name'] = self.app
        context['table'] = self.kwargs['table']
        context['back'] = self.back_url
        context['name'] = page_title
        context['page_title'] = page_title
        context['mybase'] = "{0}/base.html".format(self.app)
        return context
```

Comment: You don't seem to be using class-based views here at all, you're just rendering a template from a function view.

Comment: Yes,I am saying that I tried to call the html. But those html "belong" to class-based views. That's why I am wondering if I am thinking it correctly here, or how should I approach that matter

Comment: But that isn't a thing. Templates don't "belong" to views.

Comment: You are right. I am trying to wrap my head around what I should do. Basically I need one url to check if the object has been created and either updated it or create it. And I am wondering if it can be created or updated throught class-based views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have created working CreateView and UpdateView (I'm assuming we are talking about django's View subclasses), set proper templates **inside of them**, and then return correct views:

```
def getArchived(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q',None)
    try:
        archived = Archivedfolder.objects.get(folder=q)
        return DataUpdate.as_view()(
            request,
            is_list=is_list,
            table=table,
            pk=pk
        ) 
    except Archivedfolder.DoesNotExist:
        return CreateView.as_view()(request)
```

**EDIT**

If you have `is_list`, `table` and `pk` parameters in your url, you'd get them in View as parameters next to `request`. Also you use them as `kwargs`, so don't forget about argument's name. Edited code above.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried that with `return DataUpdate.as_view()(request)` ,where DataUpdate is the name of my UpdateView and I get a KeyError. I think I must pass the arguments of the url . My urls is `url(r'^(?P<is_list>\d+)/(?P<table>[\w|\W]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$',DataUpdate.as_view(),
        name='data-update')` . Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: @DanaeVogiatzi pass them as arguments. I've edited answer.

Comment: yeah,I stll get the KeyError ,for 'table' to be precise

Comment: @DanaeVogiatzi can you add whole DataUpdate class to your question?

Comment: I've posted it!

Comment: Ok, you look for `table` in kwargs, so we need it to be in kwargs! Try `return DataUpdate.as_view()(request, is_list=is_list, table=table, pk=pk)`

Comment: YEAH!! that worked!! thank you!!!! Could you please update your answer so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I do have another error. I tried it on a new object so I can test the CreateView... and I get DowsNotExist error , matching query does not exist. Shouldn't it go to the except: if it does not exist?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142735/discussion-between-mateusz-knapczyk-and-danae-vogiatzi).